# Codeigniter - Templating with separate templates

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I wish to have a codeigniter application with 3 templates.

1. a template for displaying a login view, or an error view.
2. a template with header body navigation
3. a template with header body sidebar footer

now I can build the codeigniter application, but I can't find a simple template system to accomplish this task.  There are many recommendations for libraries available, but they lack implementation details.

Suggestions and guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can user CodeIgniter Template. 
http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/index.html 
Download here the library and also you have a full documentation.

With this library, you can use more than one template, and you can manage it easy and separate in groups.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple once you get your head around it.

You need to create a view file for each of the things you've listed above, so you'll want something like this (folder/file wise):

```
views/page-login.php
views/page-error.php
views/header.php
views/footer.php
```

Then from your controller you will load one of the page views.
Within the page view you can then load the elements you require, so header and footer with the page specific code between them.

So for example your login page could be:

```
<?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>

    <h1>Login</h1>
    <p>Please login to my website.</p>

<?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
```

Comment: I like this suggestion a lot, but would this way be easy to maintain the same style and continuity

Comment: I've used CI on several large sites. I always lay my code out this way. I've never had a need to change it. I prefer to pull modules into my page, rather than pulling my page into a template, personal taste really.

Comment: this way appears to be less technically complicated, is there any pitfalls in organising the site like this.

Comment: No pitfalls that I'm aware of. This follows the natural non-MVC PHP structure where you'd include a header and footer in every page. Try it yourself and see how you get on, if you did have a problem it wouldn't take a long time to change to a different method.

Comment: lastly would this work with say a sidebar view changing the main content view

Comment: Should do. I would assume your sidebar had `href=""` to direct the user to the appropriate controller method, which would then just load in another view with the same template structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple.

A quick example:

In your controller you can put

```
//a test variable
$data["foo"] = 'bar';
$data["page"] = 'a_page'; // this will make sure it loads the views/pages/a_page.php in your template
$this->load->view('templates/login',$data);
```

And in your `views/template/login.php` you can put:

```
<!-- your login template html  -->
<html>
    ...
    <!-- include the view you want inside your login template -->
    <?php $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);?><!-- As you can see it loads /views/pages/a_page.php -->
    <?php echo $foo;?> //This will echo Bar
</html>
```

or:

```
<?php $this->load->view('template/login_header');?>
<?php $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);?>
<?php $this->load->view('template/login_footer');?>
```

`views/pages/a_page.php` will also know `$foo`.

This loads another view (views/pages/a_page.php) in your template.

This way you can create all the templates you want, and include your view in those templates.

TIP: Handling headers & footers this way get's unmanageable pretty quickly. And it's still better to use template libraries.  Try [Phil sturgeon's library](http://getsparks.org/packages/template/show)

Comment: on re-reading your answer I can write my template up something like this (roughly)

`<body>
<div nav>
</div nav>
<div content>
<?php $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);?>
</div content>
<div footer>
</div footer>
</body>`

but im confused with the 
`$data["page"] = 'a_page';
$this->load->view('templates/login',$data);`

to use it to load a form for instance

Comment: That looks fine, and everything you put in $data, will be accessible in you page. For example if you add $data["foo"] = "bar";  and you add print_r($foo) in you /views/pages/a_page.php It will print "bar" no problem.

Comment: so to clarify `$data = array(
               'name'        => 'username',
               'id'          => 'username',
               'value'       => 'johndoe',
               'maxlength'   => '100',
               'size'        => '50',
               'style'       => 'width:50%',
             );
` would work as well?

Comment: Yes, but don't forget 'page'=>'a_page' too ;)  And read my tip : Handling headers & footers this way get's unmanageable pretty quickly. Best way is do some more research on having a good templating library which you can use. Unless it's not that big of a deal.